# Eigenvalues 'on' Unit Circle - Stability Characteristics?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

If the eigenvalues of the system matrix contains most of the Eigenvalues exactly "on" the boundary of the unit circle, with a very few actually inside - What does it imply about the stability characteristics?
I understand Eigenvalues lying inside are stable and those outside are unstable, however I am unable to get an intuitive feel for the Eigenvalues on the boundary itself.

Comment: If you're working with linear system, eigenvalues on unit circle still make system Lyapunov stable, but system is no longer asymptotically Lyapunov stable. Loosely speaking, in linear case presence of eigenvalues on unit circle cause that trajectory stays on some closed and bounded hypersurface (like circle in 2D-case or cylinder in 3D case). In case of nonlinear systems it's not necessarily so; here come to play other, nonlinear terms of mapping.

Comment: Thanks. Since these eigenvals are from a linear approximation of a highly nonlinear phenomenon, I think I should be careful before calling the system "stable", without further analysis.

Comment: Yes, of course. Linear approximation models the behaviour of trajectory in the neighbourhood of fixed or periodic point qualitatively if this point is hyperbolic, i.e. no eigenvalues on unit circle. As far as I know, theory of center manifolds deals with describing behaviour of trajectories in other cases.